# Track tags in Google Analytics?

Tags: tags, google-analytics

I'd like to track tags for our posts in GA. Is there a way to submit them and have them associated the same way they apply in Wordpress, so that you can see how a particular tag is doing?

For example, we would be able to see how all posts tagged "movies" and "Vin Diesel" are doing. This seems like it should be a common enough issue, but I didn't see a great solution in my searching.

Right now our best idea is to submit all the tags in one long string. Then to analyze we have to do a data extract and some manipulation. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#pageLevel) for Google Analytics. In that case you would need to parse all used tags as one string (maybe separated by | for example), because it's better to use one variable name and each variable can take one value per pageview.

Another option would be using [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide), using a category (named tags for example), which you could repeat for all tags used on a page. I think that is the best solution, since you can fire the same event category multiple times in one pageview. And this way you can search and compare the values within GA easily.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping I missed something. We'll cram them all into a custom var.